# Specific Coloring on Google Sankey Diagrams

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Let's say I've a sankey diagram with 4 different 'from' values.
A, B, C, D.

And I've data like;

```
['C', 'A*', 4],
['A', 'B*', 5],
['A', 'B*', 7],
['B', 'A*', 6],
['B', 'C*', 2],
['A', 'C*', 9]
```

Order changes everytime when page refresh (and data, too), so it doesn't start from A, and sometimes it doesn't have A.

I defined colors,

```
var colors = ['green', 'crimson', 'yellow', 'darkorange'];
```

and I want to make A's green, B's crimson, C's yellow. But I couldn't set the specific colors.

What can I do?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/m7qyp6a6/

I tried to use 'zero-valued' data to set colors, but it didn't work :)

```
[['A', 'A*', 0],['B', 'B*', 0],['C', 'C*', 0],['D', 'D*', 0]];
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. I get that you want to map `A` to `green` but I do not understand which type of array gets mapped to `A`. Does `['A', 'B*', 5]` get mapped to A? In other words, is the first element of the array the element that holds the character representation?

Comment: @JeffMandell Yes. If the first element is A, it should be green. If it's D, it should be darkorange.